# Revert contact ringtone to default

Tags: contacts, ringtone

After selecting a non-default ringtone for a contact I apparently cannot revert it to the default ringtone anymore. Of course I can select the same ringtone but when changing the default ringtone that contact will still have the old one.

Is there a way to remove the custom ringtone from the contact and make it use the global default ringtone again? In case it matters, the phone is a HTC One V

Comment: Don't you have something called "Default" or something? Here's mine. http://i.imgur.com/cxUsP.png

Comment: Nope, I just have the "Default 1"..."Default 8" ringtones in the list next to the other ones which were already on the phone and none of them is the actual "default ringtone".

Comment: Bleh, looks like a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30193

Comment: Ouch, bummer. How could they something like that slide through.

Comment: And the HTC support is helpful like always. It's an obvious bug. So why do they ask me for my device serial number etc.?